# Cast postgresql jsonb value as array of int and remove element from it

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to remove int value from jsonb array of ints in json stored in jsonb value type in db.

I have a json value, like:

```
select '{"a":[1,3]}'::jsonb->'a'

?column?
----------
[1, 3]
(1 row)
```

And i want to remove '1' from it, like that:

```
select array_remove(ARRAY[1,1,2,3], 1);
 array_remove
--------------
 {2,3}
(1 row)
```

But if i do something like that:

```
select array_remove(array('{"a":[1,3]}'::jsonb->'a'), 1);
```

or:

```
select array_remove('{"a":[1,3]}'::jsonb->'a'::text::int[], 1);
```

I have an error like:

```
operator does not exist: jsonb -> integer[]
```

How can i cast json value to array to remove value from it?

Answer (score 0):

For now, you basically have to expand the array to individual values, filter those values, and then create a new array:

```
with data(original) as (VALUES ('{"a":[1,1,2,3]}'::jsonb), ('{"a":[2,3,4,5,1]}'::jsonb))
select original->'a', filtered
from data
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT jsonb_agg(value) as filtered 
              from jsonb_array_elements(original->'a') j(value) 
              WHERE value::int != 1) as filtered ON TRUE;
    ?column?     |   filtered
-----------------+--------------
 [1, 1, 2, 3]    | [2, 3]
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 1] | [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

In postgres 12, you'll be able to use the jsonb_path functions.  The syntax is a bit difficult to parse, but it doesn't involve any joins:

```
with data(original) as (VALUES ('{"a":[1,1,2,3]}'::jsonb), ('{"a":[2,3,4,5,1]}'::jsonb))
select original->'a', 
       jsonb_path_query_array(original, '$.a[*] ? (@ != $filter)', '{"filter":1}')
from data;
    ?column?     | jsonb_path_query_array
-----------------+------------------------
 [1, 1, 2, 3]    | [2, 3]
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 1] | [2, 3, 4, 5]
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, i tested it and it seems to be worked. But why i can't just use array_remove function?
And actually i need to update that array in my original json field, now i'm trying to implement it. If you have some advices it would be useful.

Comment: array_remove is for an array type, not json or jsonb.  You could expand the json array with jsonb_array_elements, use array_agg, to make an int[] and then use array_remove, but that's just an extra step.